# Need to select image form custom widget in android

Tags: android, gallery

I am creating a custom control. I need to open gallery from it and use the selected image for some purpose. This is a huge application so please dont tell me about intents and onActivityResult as I need to do it from widget and not App, activity, fragment etc

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/15236235/1915697 it ??

Comment: like i said I cannot recieve the result in Activity. Try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searching came to the conclusion that it is not possible at all.